# Will std::lower_bound be logarithmic for list<>?

Tags: c++, binary-search, lower-bound

Suppose I have a `list<int>` and maintaining it in ordered state. Can I isert new values into it with logarithmic complexity with code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list<int> data) {
    for(auto it=data.begin(); it!=data.end(); ++it) {
        if(it!=data.begin()) {
            out << ", ";
        }
        out << (*it);
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {

    const int max = 100;
    mt19937 gen;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, max);
    list<int> data;

    for(int i=0; i<max; ++i) {
        int val = dist(gen);

        auto it = lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), val);
        data.insert(it, val);

    }

    cout << data << endl;
}
```

I would say not, because it is impossible to position iterator in `list` in `O(1)` but [documentation says strange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance
> between first and last (At most log2(last - first) + O(1)
> comparisons). However, for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number
> of iterator increments is linear. Notably, std::set and std::multiset
> iterators are not random access, and so their member functions
> std::set::lower_bound (resp. std::multiset::lower_bound) should be
> preferred.

i.e. it doesn't recomment to use this function for `set` which is alterady search tree internally. Which containers this function is inteded to use then? How to insert and maintain sorted then?

Comment: it is intended to be used on containers that can be unsorted in priciple but are sorted. For example a sorted `std::vector`. Containers that are sorted always typically have more efficient ways to find the lower bound, such as eg `set::lower_bound`

Comment: `std::list` compares generally poor against `std::vector`. From the top of my head I am not aware of a case where a `std::list` is superior. It has stable iterators, but it doesnt look like you need that

Comment: anyhow, I don't quite understand what is the question. Is your code not doing what it should do? `std::list` iterators are not random access, there is not much you can do about that (other than not using `std::list`)

Comment: If you want an ordered container with logarithmic insertion then use `std::multiset` (or `std::set` if you don't want duplicates). You will not have to bother with `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: And about 'which containers is this function intended to be used on' - well, any, that's the point. Depending on the type of iterator, you get different speed, but you should know that already when you choose one container over the other. If you have a sorted vector and need to find a certain element, it's fast and readable. If you have a sorted `std::list`, then it's as fast as possible anyway (because of list limitations) and readable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: A classical case for lists is a FIFO; vector has no `push_front` or `pop_front`.

Comment: @MSalters It's not a particularly good data structure for FIFO through. `std::deque` is often better, or a "shift" vector.

Comment: *"Will `std::lower_bound` be logarithmic for `list<>`?"*. With complexity, we have to be precise about **what** do you want to count. It is logarithmic for the number of comparisons with provided element (which by itself might have a complexity depending of its size as `operator<` for `std::string`); Moving iterator has its own complexity too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will std::lower_bound be logarithmic for list<>?

No. Quote from documentation:

> for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is **linear**.

---

> Which containers this function is inteded to use then?

`std::lower_bound` is intended for any container that is - or can be - ordered, and doesn't have faster lower bound algorithm that relies on its internal structure - which excludes `std::set` and `std::multiset` as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Ergo, the only suitable container is `vector`, which is not `O(1)` insertable, right?

Comment: @Dims suitable for what?

Comment: @Dims `array` and `deque` also offer random access

Comment: @Dims Any *range* who's iterators satisfy *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*, e.g. `std::ranges::views::iota(1, 1'000'000'000) | std::ranges::views::common`.

Comment: @eerorika for keeping some trail in order